# Laravel project creation - Windows Platform

Tags: php, laravel, windows, composer-php

I tried to create a laravel proyect but it throws this error.

> composer create-project laravel/laravel "path-directory" 4.2
> --prefer-dist
>
> Failed to extract laravel/laravel: (9)
> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\unzip.EXE

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

```
Could you help me solve this, please?
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you creating a Laravel4.2 project? Any reason for such an old version? Did you try just `composer create-project laravel/laravel "path-directory"` for the latest version?

Comment: I only tried the command:
composer create-project laravel/laravel "path-directory"
I guess it takes the lastest version
I am on Windows platform

Comment: I am using laravel v8.65.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem, uncommented in PHP.ini file, the following lines:

```
 - extension=fileinfo 
 - extension=mbstring
```

Then I ran the command again (in **PowerShell** from Windows).

```
> composer create-project laravel/laravel users
```

And it worked successfully. :)

Comment: Hi Abel, welcome :-) Glad that you've find a solution to the problem. I just sent an edit for your question: when writing any text here, you can use Markdown syntax, it's particularly useful when you need to include some code, by making it more readable. Also, it's not mandatory, but you can set which language is contained into your code block, by writing it's name after the three opening backticks (e.g.: ```html ). It will highlight keywords, variables, etc. Here's an [article for you](https://shorturl.at/iBT56). Happy coding :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks for telling me this. I didn't know it.
For sure, next posts will keep improving.

Comment: Hello @funder7 
There, I could format the question a bit more. I hope it helps better now.
Sorry to add another Question to the same thread.

Comment: Hey, no worries :-) Good job!